# Cypress never get past loading screen on Windows

Tags: node.js, testing, npm, automation, cypress

I have created a new project by using node

```
npm init -y
```

Installed cypress

```
npm install cypres --save-dev
```

Run cypress

```
npx cypress open
```

Cypress will open the Screen, but it will only load instead of showing my files

[image]

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you run `cypress verify` in the root directory of the project where the cypress is installed and tell me the result?

Comment: Also, check your firewall for blocking.

Comment: It was a Windows Update. Also, they released a new update, and it seems that everything is working properly now.